# Do I need to write a TLC for my Sfunction in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a Simulink model that needs to integrate a external EXE. (I do not have access to EXE source code).

I was thinking in using a Sfunction to call this EXE and handle all inputs/ouputs.

Since I am a completelly newbie in Sfunctions, I am wondering if it is necessary to write a Sfunction TLC in order to make my model run in compiled mode? Does it make any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what language you are going to write the S-Function in.

To use an m-code S-Function with Simulink Coder you will need to write a tlc file.

TO use a c-mex S-Function with Simulink Coder you do not need to write a tlc file unless you want to in-line the code.

Comment: Sorry if the question is too simple, but what is "inline the code"?  Also, I have verified that C-mex and m-code S-Function are quite similars in syntax. I´m considering writing a c-mex , skipping m-code. What do you think?

Comment: Inlining is only something to worry about if you intend using Simulink Coder, and only relevant for c-mex S-Functions.  The code within a non-inlined S-Function gets incorporated into the Simulink Coder generated code as function calls, while the code within an inlined S-Function gets "sucked into" the source code. As to which language to use, it depends on your familiarity with C and MATLAB.  The C will be faster, but the MATLAB may be more convenient.